# Angular 2: page not found

Tags: angular

I was having [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10626), and it seems that the recommended workaround is to remove the moduleId from all components. event I don't really understand how this could be a valid workaround, I tried it.

But now I've "Not found" exception for most of my templates files. What path should I indicate now? Or is there a better workaround?

Comment: Can you post some code? In general for template not found errors, make sure your template refs start with ./

Comment: @MikeOne I'm testing something, but I think I found how to solve it: using `template: require('my.component.html')` instead of my initial `templateUrl: 'my.component.html`. I've some others issues now, so I cannot yet confirm this is definitely solving my issue

Comment: It should be templateUrl: './my.component.html'